# singular value of Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $ A \epsilon R^{m*n}$ and its singular values are equal to (σ1, σ2, ..., σ) that  = min (, ). get the eigenvalues of:
$$ G=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & A \\
        A^* & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Comment: This might help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that the non-zero eigenvalues of $A^*A$ and $AA^*$ are the same and that the $\sigma_k$'s are the square roots of these eigenvalues, right? So, choose $k\in\{1,\ldots,p\}$ and let $y\neq 0$ be a vector such that $A^*Ay = \sigma_k^2y$. Note that $Ay\neq 0$. Define $x := \sigma_k^{-1}Ay\neq 0$. Denoting your block operator matrix by $M$, we get that $(M-\sigma_k I)(x,y)^T = 0$ and also $(M + \sigma_k I)(-x,y)^T = 0$. Hence, both $\pm\sigma_k$ are eigenvalues of $M$. Since $\ker M$ is easily seen to be $\ker(A^*)\times\ker A$, the matrix $M$ can only be invertible if $A$ is invertible (for which $m=n$) is necessary. Thus, zero is an eigenvalue of $M$ if and only if $m\neq n$ or if $A$ is singular when $m=n$.

To see that the non-zero eigenvalues of $M$ are exactly the $\pm\sigma_k$'s, let $(M-\lambda I)(x,y)^T=0$ for some non-zero $\lambda$ and $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. Then we get $A^*x = \lambda y$ and $Ay = \lambda x$. Hence, $AA^*x = \lambda^2 x$ and $A^*Ay = \lambda^2y$. As one of $x$ and $y$ must be non-zero, we obtain $\lambda^2 = \sigma_k^2$ for some $k$ and hence $\lambda = \pm\sigma_k$.

Therefore, the eigenvalues of $M$ are $\pm\sigma_1,\ldots,\pm\sigma_p$ if $m=n$ and $A$ is invertible (in which case $m=n=p$) or $0,\pm\sigma_1,\ldots\pm\sigma_p$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. your answer was very helpful.